# Jquery collision of 2 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, collision

First of all I'm very happy to be apart of the Stackoverflow community! Been reading for almost a year now and I've always found very useful bits here and there.

I've been trying to code a very simple collision function in jquery but can't seem to find the issue with my code.

http://ns366377.ovh.net/siow/perso/game/ (link to see the latest version to understand)

```
if (cubeleft < moneyleft < cubeleft + cubewidth && moneytop >= 485 ){
console.log("ok");
}
else{
console.log("no")
}
```

The point of this game is very simple, on collision 1 point is added to the total. The thing is, it does not verify the first part of the function and only takes in count "moneytop >= 485" which makes it non functional. (Please forgive for the console.log with 1ms interval !).

Please let me know if I omitted anything in my explanation and thank you in advance !

Cheers,
Ashtear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript you can't have compound compare statements like:

`cubeleft < moneyleft < cubeleft`

Instead you should seperate them into pairs and AND them all together.

```
if ((cubeleft < moneyleft) && (moneyleft < cubeleft + cubewidth) && (moneytop >= 485)){ ... }
```

Comment: Your welcome! Just a quick tip about styling, using parenthesis helps you easily see what is happening in Boolean statements.